# Linq many to many relation Join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have 4 tables, `UserCredential`, `UserProfile`, `UserRoles` and `Role`

```
var user = (from uc in Db.UserCredentials
                join up in Db.UserProfiles on uc.UserId equals up.UserId
                join ur in Db.UserRoles on uc.UserId equals ur.UserId
                select new {
                    Credetial = uc, 
                    Profile = up, 
                    Roles = Db.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId == ur.RoleId)})
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

`UserRole` has `UserId` and `RoleId`, so user can have multiple roles.

Query generated by the above code doesn't seem to be efficient. Can anyone suggest a better code

Comment: EF automatically creates navigation properties for relationship so you don't need to use joins.

Comment: You indicate EF and LINQ to SQL. Which are you using? The SQL generated by each can be very different. Post the generated SQL and indicate where you feel it is inefficient. Regardless, consider thinking about this as an object graph rather than sets with joins and you may find a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since we're worried about performance, make sure your database has indexes on all of those UserId and RoleId columns.

Since you have multiple UserRoles, including it in the join wastefully increases the cardinality of your query, and then subsequently calling FirstOrDefault pulls it back down to one.  one? you haven't shown how you select a particular user, but I'll leave that up to you to fix, unless it's filtered in one of your data sources.

Also, the roles property on your anonymous object:  Every time you touch it you will be hitting the database.  This very well could be the source of the performance problems.  If it's acceptable to cache that information, finishing up the subquery with a ToList() call would be prudent.

That subquery itself could be another source of trouble, especially if using ToList - it'll be another trip to the database, so make sure you keep the cardinality of the main query low to control the number of trips.

```
var user = (from uc in Db.UserCredentials
            join up in Db.UserProfiles on uc.UserId equals up.UserId
            //where uc.UserId == somePassedInUserId    /* add this line if your datasources aren't filtered */
            select new {
                Credetial = uc, 
                Profile = up, 
                Roles = (from ur in Db.UserRoles join r in Db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.RoleId
                           where ur.UserId == uc.UserId select r).ToList()
            .FirstOrDefault();
```